# pagination on shopify collection page

Tags: shopify

I want to modify the pagination on the collection page in shopify. I want to show products in four category like first should be - 20, second - 30, third - 40 and fourth should be - All products. The pagination will work also on the collection page. Like -

View:  20  |  30  |  40  |  ALL
Below is my code. But it is not working. I want to filter products by number.

```html
{% case section.settings.grid %}
  {% when '2' %}
    {%- assign max_height = 530 -%}
  {% when '3' %}
    {%- assign max_height = 345 -%}
  {% when '4' %}
    {%- assign max_height = 250 -%}
  {% when '5' %}
    {%- assign max_height = 195 -%}
{% endcase %}

{% if section.settings.layout == 'grid' %}
{%- assign limit = cart.attributes.pagination -%}
{% else %}
{%- assign limit = cart.attributes.pagination -%}
{% endif %}
{{cart.attributes.pagination}}

{% paginate collection.products limit %}

<div data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="collection-template">
  <header class="collection-header">

  
<label for="paginateBy">Paginate By</label>
<select name="paginateBy" id="paginateBy">
  {% for i in (1..50) %}
    {% assign v = i | append:'' %}
    <option value="{{ v }}"{% if cart.attributes.pagination != blank and cart.attributes.pagination %}{% if cart.attributes.pagination == v %} selected{% endif %}{% else %}{% if i == 40 %} selected{% endif %}{% endif %}>{{ i }} per page</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>  
  
    {% if section.settings.show_collection_image and collection.image %}
      <div class="collection-hero">
        <div class="collection-hero__image ratio-container lazyload js"
             data-bgset="{% include 'bgset', image: collection.image %}"
             data-sizes="auto"
             data-parent-fit="cover"
             style="background-image: url('{{ collection.image | img_url: '300x300' }});"></div>
        <noscript>
          <div class="collection-hero__image" style="background-image: url({{ collection.image | img_url: '2048x600', crop: 'top' }});"></div>
        </noscript>
        <div class="collection-hero__title-wrapper">
          <h1 class="collection-hero__title page-width">{{ collection.title }}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      {% if collection.description != blank %}
        <div class="rte collection-description page-width">
          {{ collection.description }}
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    
    
    {% else %}
      <div class="page-width">
        <div class="section-header text-center">
          <h1>{{ collection.title }}</h1>
          {% if collection.description != blank %}
            <div class="rte">
              {{ collection.description }}
            </div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
    
    {% if paginate.pages > 1 %}
      {% include 'pagination' %}
    {% endif %}
    
    {% if section.settings.tags_enable or section.settings.sort_enable %}
      <div class="filters-toolbar-wrapper">
        <div class="page-width">
          <div class="filters-toolbar">
            {% if section.settings.tags_enable %}
              <div class="filters-toolbar__item">
                <label for="SortTags" class="label--hidden">{{ 'collections.filters.title_tags' | t }}</label>
                <select class="filters-toolbar__input filters-toolbar__input--filter hidden" name="SortTags" id="SortTags">
                  {% if current_tags %}
                    {% if collection.handle %}
                      <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">{{ 'collections.filters.all_tags' | t }}</option>
                    {% elsif collection.current_type %}
                      <option value="{{ collection.current_type | url_for_type }}">{{ 'collections.filters.all_tags' | t }}</option>
                    {% elsif collection.current_vendor %}
                      <option value="{{ collection.current_vendor | url_for_vendor }}">{{ 'collections.filters.all_tags' | t }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                  {% else %}
                    {% if current_tags contains tag %}
                      <option value="">{{ 'collections.filters.all_tags' | t }}</option>
                    {% else %}
                      <option value="">{{ 'collections.filters.title_tags' | t }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endif %}
                  {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
                    <option value="/collections/{% if collection.handle != blank %}{{ collection.handle }}{% else %}all{% endif %}/{{ tag | handleize }}"{% if current_tags contains tag %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ tag }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
              </div>
            {% endif %}

            <div class="filters-toolbar__item filters-toolbar__item--count">
              <span class="filters-toolbar__product-count">{{ 'collections.general.items_with_count' | t: count: collection.products_count }}</span>
            </div>

            {% if section.settings.sort_enable %}
              <div class="filters-toolbar__item text-right">
                {%- assign sort_by = collection.sort_by | default: collection.default_sort_by -%}
                <label for="SortBy" class="label--hidden">{{ 'collections.sorting.title' | t }}</label>
                <select name="SortBy" id="SortBy" class="filters-toolbar__input filters-toolbar__input--sort hidden">
                  {% if sort_by == collection.default_sort_by %}
                    <option value="title-ascending" selected="selected">{{ 'collections.sorting.title' | t }}</option>
                    {% if collection.default_sort_by != 'manual' %}
                      <option value="manual"{% if sort_by == "manual" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.featured' | t }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if collection.default_sort_by != 'best-selling' %}
                      <option value="best-selling"{% if sort_by == "best-selling" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.best_selling' | t }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if collection.default_sort_by != 'title-ascending' %}
                      <option value="title-ascending"{% if sort_by == "title-ascending"  %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.az' | t }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if collection.default_sort_by != 'title-descending' %}
                      <option value="title-descending"{% if sort_by == "title-descending" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.za' | t }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if collection.default_sort_by != 'price-ascending' %}
                      <option value="price-ascending"{% if sort_by == "price-ascending" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.price_ascending' | t }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if collection.default_sort_by != 'price-descending' %}
                      <option value="price-descending"{% if sort_by == "price-descending" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.price_descending' | t }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if collection.default_sort_by != 'created-descending' %}
                      <option value="created-descending"{% if sort_by == "created-descending" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.date_descending' | t }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if collection.default_sort_by != 'created-ascending' %}
                      <option value="created-ascending"{% if sort_by == "created-ascending" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.date_ascending' | t }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                  {% else %}
                    <option value="manual"{% if sort_by == "manual" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.featured' | t }}</option>
                    <option value="best-selling"{% if sort_by == "best-selling" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.best_selling' | t }}</option>
                    <option value="title-ascending"{% if sort_by == "title-ascending"  %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.az' | t }}</option>
                    <option value="title-descending"{% if sort_by == "title-descending" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.za' | t }}</option>
                    <option value="price-ascending"{% if sort_by == "price-ascending" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.price_ascending' | t }}</option>
                    <option value="price-descending"{% if sort_by == "price-descending" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.price_descending' | t }}</option>
                    <option value="created-descending"{% if sort_by == "created-descending" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.date_descending' | t }}</option>
                    <option value="created-ascending"{% if sort_by == "created-ascending" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ 'collections.sorting.date_ascending' | t }}</option>
                  {% endif %}
                </select>
                <input id="DefaultSortBy" type="hidden" value="{{ collection.default_sort_by }}">
              </div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </header>

  <div class="page-width" id="Collection">
    {% if section.settings.layout == 'grid' %}
      {% case section.settings.grid %}
      {% when '2' %}
        {%- assign grid_item_width = 'medium-up--one-half' -%}
      {% when '3' %}
        {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-third' -%}
      {% when '4' %}
        {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-quarter' -%}
      {% when '5' %}
        {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-fifth' -%}
      {% endcase %}

      <div class="grid grid--uniform{% if collection.products_count > 0 %} grid--view-items{% endif %}">
        {% for product in collection.products %}
          <div class="grid__item grid__item--{{section.id}} {{ grid_item_width }}">
            {% include 'product-card-grid', max_height: max_height %}
          </div>
        {% else %}
          {% comment %}
          Add default products to help with onboarding for collections/all only.

          The onboarding styles and products are only loaded if the
          store has no products.
          {% endcomment %}
          {% if collection.handle == 'all' and collection.all_vendors.size == 0 and collection.all_types.size == 0 %}
            <div class="grid__item">
              <div class="grid grid--uniform">
                {% for i in (1..limit) %}
                  <div class="grid__item {{ grid_item_width }}">
                    <div class="grid-view-item">
                      <a href="#" class="grid-view-item__link">
                        <div class="grid-view-item__image">
                          {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 %}{% endcapture %}
                          {{ 'product-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="h4 grid-view-item__title">{{ 'homepage.onboarding.product_title' | t }}</div>
                        <div class="grid-view-item__meta">
                          <span class="product-price__price">$19.99</span>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
          {% else %}
            {%- assign is_empty_collection = true -%}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% else %}
      <div class="list-view-items">
        {% for product in collection.products %}
          <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" class="list-view-item">
            {% include 'product-card-list', product: product %}
          </a>
        {% else %}

          {% comment %}
          Add default products to help with onboarding for collections/all only.

          The onboarding styles and products are only loaded if the
          store has no products.
          {% endcomment %}
          {% if collection.handle == 'all' and collection.all_vendors.size == 0 and collection.all_types.size == 0%}
            {% for i in (1..4) %}
              <a href="#" class="list-view-item">
                <div class="list-view-item__image-column">
                  <div class="list-view-item__image-wrapper">
                    <div class="list-view-item__image">
                      {%- assign placeholder = 'placeholder-product-' | append: i -%}
                      {% include placeholder %}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="list-view-item__title-column">
                  <div class="list-view-item__title">{{ 'homepage.onboarding.product_title' | t }}</div>
                </div>

                <div class="list-view-item__price-column">
                  <span class="product-price__price">$19.99</span>
                </div>
              
              </a>
            {% endfor %}
          {% else %}
            {%- assign is_empty_collection = true -%}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if is_empty_collection %}
      <div class="grid__item small--text-center">
        <p class="text-center">{{ 'collections.general.no_matches' | t }}</p>
      </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if paginate.pages > 1 %}
      {% include 'pagination' %}
    {% endif %}
    
  </div>
</div>

{% endpaginate %}

<script>
  /* Bind a change event to the dropdown */
  $('#paginateBy').on('change', function(){
    /* Get the current value. Some value validation could be added here (but we don't) */
    var val = $(this).val();
    /* Send the value as a cart attribute via the AJAX API */
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/cart.js',
      data: {"attributes[pagination]": val}, /* We are using an attribute named "pagination" */
      success: function(d){
        window.location.reload();
      },
      dataType: 'json'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried on your own?

Comment: I have now default pagination on my collection page. I want to add view products field on the left side and pagination on the right side. Like -  View: 20 | 30 | 40 | ALL                                              Page 1 of 6  Previous  |  1  |  2  | Next

Comment: What you are describing in your comment is the default pagination functionality of the Shopify, not what you are looking for if I'm correct. I'm asking what have you tried to code, since from my perspective it looks like you are asking to write the code for you and not to help you with your own code, which is not what StackOverflow is for.